# gcc-4.9.2: non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have a weird compilation error on gcc-4.9.2, where the same code worked on other compilers, like gcc-4.8 or any clang I could get hold of. The problem is related to [non-type template-arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). So consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

int templateParam;

template <int &D> struct TestTemplate {
    int value() {}
};

template <> int TestTemplate<templateParam>::value() {
    return templateParam;
}

TestTemplate<templateParam> testVariable;

int main() {

    std::cout << testVariable.value() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error with gcc-4.9.2:

```
prog.cpp:10:17: error: prototype for 'int TestTemplate<D>::value() [with int& D = (* & templateParam)]' does not match any in class 'TestTemplate<(*  & templateParam)>'
 template <> int TestTemplate<templateParam>::value() {
                 ^
prog.cpp:7:9: error: candidate is: int TestTemplate<D>::value() [with int& D = (* & templateParam)]
     int value() {}
         ^
```

these two ideones make it clearer:

- [gcc-4.9.2](http://ideone.com/EEC67F)
- [gcc-4.3.2](http://ideone.com/5RfpuA)

Is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a compiler bug?

Yes, I think it was https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63658 and will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: hmpf, not what I hoped ;-( Thanks anyways. So based on the bugreport one workaround is to use pointers instead of references (tried it)

Comment: To add, [`gcc-4.3.2`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html) is more that 6 years old.

Comment: yeah, but its the one provided by ideone... Tried all the compilers available in Jessie...